# error in my image preloader jquery code on setInterval

Tags: jquery, image, preloader

Hi everybody i have an error in my image preloader jquery code on setInterval please help if you have any other mated to achieve this, i want to hide all images within  `div image-box`  and when document is fully loaded fadeIn images 1 after 1, below is my code

```
    var i = 0;
    var int=0;
    jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
        var int = setInterval("loadimg(i)",300);
    });
    function loadimg() {

        var imgs = jQuery('.image-box img').length;
        if (i >= imgs ) {
            clearInterval(int);
        }
        // fadein images 1 after 1 with 0.3 seconds delay
        jQuery('.image-box img').eq(i).fadeIn({'opacity': '1', 'display': 'block'}, 300);
        jQuery('.image-box').eq(i).addClass('done');
        i++;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "load" handler, the "int" variable should not be declared with `var`:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    int = setInterval("loadimg(i)",300);
});
```

(Also "int" is probably not the best variable name, as it's likely to cause minor brain seizures in C/C++/Java programmers who look at the code.)

You don't need that string version of the function call code in your "setInterval" initialization either:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    int = setInterval(loadimg, 300);
});
```

You did not explain what the "error" is, so it's hard to provide more help than that.

Comment: after loading page my browser is halted i am using firefox and fireug stop on line 4

Comment: <code>var int = setInterval('loadimg()', 300); </code> on this line firebug is stop working, is there any other way/script to achieve this goal

Comment: Try using a different variable name, like "interval".

Answer (score 0):

try to use this plugin "myimagepreloader". Here is the link [myimagepreloader](http://plugins2.jquery.com/project/myimagepreloader)